# Reasons Flash Page is Locked Due

Tags: arduino-due, flash

Using the [Arduino Due](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/due) on a project, I have found that I commonly run into the issue `Flash Page is Locked` when attempting to upload.

I have used the library write functions of [DueFlashStorage](https://github.com/sebnil/DueFlashStorage/blob/master/src/DueFlashStorage.cpp#L20-L89) that [lock](https://github.com/sebnil/DueFlashStorage/blob/master/src/DueFlashStorage.cpp#L83) and unlock addresses on each write. I believe a combination of this locking/unlocking and power loss during writes has caused my woes. This lib has added functions that avoid locking/unlocking memory on each write so this problem could be averted in that way.

My question is, are there other common actions that can cause the flash to lock? If I ran blink on a Due for a long period of time power cycling it randomly would the same error eventually occur? This seems to be a common issue with the due but beyond this library I have not found other causes.

Comment: the count of writes to flash si limited. with the flash library you can write data to flash. did you do many writes to flash?

Comment: For my current setup I do write to flash but not close to 10,000 times before the flash page locks and it becomes complicated to reprogram the due. I'm using 10,000 as a conservative maximum. If I did not write to flash in my program is there any reason why the flash would become locked?